# Criando o banco com migration laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Sei que com `migration` eu consigo criar as tabelas, porém tem alguma forma de automatiza até mesmo a criação do banco com o `migration` para seguir como base utilizo o `Laravel 5.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a **documentação** as `migrations` não criam o banco de dados:

`Migrations` são como controle de versão para seu banco de dados, permitindo uma equipe de modificar e compartilhar o `schema` da aplicação facilmente.

O `Laravel` `Schema` `facade` fornece um suporte agnóstico para criação e manipulação de tabelas. Ele compartilha o mesmo modelo, `API` `fluente` em todos os sitemas de banco de dados suportados pelo `Laravel`. [doc](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/5.1/migrations#introduction)

Algo que pode ser feito é criar um arquivo `PHP` para fazer isso.

**Exemplo:**

```
$pdo = $db->connect();

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$query = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `{$dbName}`";
$pdo->exec($query);

$query = "CREATE DATABASE `{$dbName}`";
$pdo->exec($query);

$query = "USE `{$dbName}`";
$pdo->exec($query);

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$query = "
    CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
        `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `nome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `endereco` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `enderecoCobranca` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
        `importancia` INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `tipoCliente` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        `numId` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL
    )";
$pdo->exec($query);
```

Comment: Para automatizar isto com o Laravel, sabe como faço ? Pedir para rodar este script por fora ?

Comment: para rodar basta dar um require "nome do arquivo". Mas o problema disso é voce cercar muito bem a ele fazer apenas se nao existir o banco. pra eviar de vc perder sua aplicacao